# how can i prevent spree from loading default screen.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, spree

how can i prevent spree from loading "screen.css" by default?
i tried creating initializer with:

> Spree::Config.set(:stylesheets => "spree")

(i have spree.css in /app/assets/stylesheets/store/)
but it didn't work.

I am using spree 0.70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

occurs that Spree was still loading stylesheets described in store/all.css

removing line with "spree_core.css" helped